# Getting "TypeError: cannot read properties of undefined" but I'm getting 0 undefined values when I console.log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have this function which is supposed to return then name of an item **collection_name** that exists within a users account. In this case the user is called **hello**. This api is return an object in this case so I'm turning it into an array using **object.values**. What am I doing wrong here? (also, the "hi" that's being returned is just a place holder, I intend to actually return the **collection_name** there.

```
import Spinner from '../Spinner';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Badges() {
  const [assets, setAssets] = useState<any[]>();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const res = await fetch(
        'https://proton.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets/v1/accounts/hello'
      );
      const { data } = await res.json();
      setAssets(data);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  if (!assets) {
    return (
      <div>
        <Spinner />
      </div>
    );
  }

  const messageArray = Object.values(assets);

  return (
    <ul>
      {messageArray.map((result) => {
        const {
          0: {
            collection: { collection_name },
          },
        } = result;

        console.log(collection_name);

        return <>hi</>;
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default Badges;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot. I think this is what you wanted? Might be completely off though :) Anyways, some notable changes were

- Removed const messageArray = Object.values(assets);
- Reworked the .map inside the return

You almost had it, although I think a big part of the confusion was caused by how the data was coming back from the API. The structure of the data seemed slightly confusing....at least to me. To avoid this issue in the future, you can always back your API responses with a TypeScript interface.

```js
import Spinner from '../Spinner';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


interface Assets { 
  collections: CollectionParent[];
  templates: Template[];
  assets: string;
}

interface Template {
  collection_name: string;
  template_id: string;
  assets: string;
}

interface CollectionParent {
  assets: string;
  collection: Collection;
}

interface Collection {
  allow_notify: boolean;
  author: string;
  authorized_accounts: string[];
  collection_name: string;
  contract: string;
  created_at_block: string;
  created_at_time: string;
  img: string;
  market_fee: number;
  name: string;
}

function Badges() {
  const [assets, setAssets] = useState<Assets>();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const res = await fetch(
        "https://proton.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets/v1/accounts/hello"
      );
      const { data } = await res.json();
      setAssets(data);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  if (!assets) {
    return (
      <div>
        <Spinner />
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      {assets?.collections?.length > 0 &&
        assets.collections.map((collectionParent, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index}>{collectionParent.collection.collection_name}</li>
          );
        })}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default Badges;
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly the answer I was looking for! You're a life saver. Really appreciate your help. I agree that the api response had me going in circles but what you did I would have never been able to get to my self. Could you tell me what I could search for to learn more about that?

Comment: I updated the answer to include interfaces.

Comment: The fundamentals of interfaces in typescript are fairly intuitive.  Ultimately, you're just assigning a name and type to each property of the API response.